# Setting a UserControl property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have custom property in my Code Behind that I want to set in the XAML.

Property:

```
Public Property WindowName() As String Implements IVendorEntryEditView.WindowName
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(WindowNameProperty), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(WindowNameProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly WindowNameProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("WindowName", GetType(String), GetType(VendorEntryEditView), _
        New PropertyMetadata(""))
```

However, I'm getting an `Attached property has no setter` message in my XAML when I try to set it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="VendorEntryEditView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EntryEditUi"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Loaded="VendorEntryEditView_OnLoaded"
         local:VendorEntryEditView.WindowName="test"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
```

How can I set that property in XAML? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to set it in the XAML ? The New PropertyMetadata("") allows you to specify a default value for the property.
Is that what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'd like to set it in the XAML because it's an inherited property from our View Base class (I removed that later from the code sample) that's going to be reused and needs to be easily set. I figured in XAML would be the easiest place.

Comment: Try removing the `local:VendorEntryEditView.` prefix from the property in your XAML.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - did not work.

Comment: @MikeCole: You might need to change the opening and closing `<UserControl ...>` tags to `<local:YourViewBase ...>` as well, where `YourViewBase` is your view base class, and `local` is mapped to the correct namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just try (where your using your `UserControl`):

```
<local:VendorEntryEditView WindowName="Test Value" />
```

**or** if you have to assign this value in the xaml of the `UserControl` itself, assign it via a `Style` in `VendorEntryEditView.xaml`

```
<UserControl.Style>
  <Style>
    <Setter Property="local:VendorEntryEditView.WindowName"
            Value="Blah Name" />
  </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Comment: The second method, although not very straightforward, worked.

Comment: Yeh the straightforward approach is normally assign the DefaultValue in the code-behind when registering the DP. If any future dev looks at your code and see's a custom DP, they ought to knw where to look to check for Defaults. Your other option is just straightforward-inheritance with the base class declaring this DP.